# Rounded corners on iOS 13 page sheet

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to round the corners on an iOS page sheet view controller? Currently, iOS page sheets by default present like this:

[image: unrounded corners on fitted sheet]

But instead, I would like the corners to be like this:

[image: rounded corners in page sheet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 15 added an API to customize the corner radius of sheets, [UISheetPresentationController.preferredCornerRadius](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3801904-preferredcornerradius):

```
let myViewController = UIViewController()
myViewController.view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
myViewController.sheetPresentationController?.preferredCornerRadius = 25
present(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your view controller, you can change the `view.layer.cornerRadius` property to the value you want

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 // You can freely change this value
}
```

As an example, the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    view.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
}
```

gives me the following result:

[image: cornerRadiusExample]

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work.
In the `onAppear` method of your sheet, get the viewcontroller that is displaying the sheet using `UIApplication.shared.activeWindows.last?.rootViewController` then get the sheet viewcontroller with `presentedViewController` and do your things on it.

```
struct Example: View {
@State var showSheet = true
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Text("hello")
                .onAppear {
                    if let controller = UIApplication.shared.activeWindows.last?.rootViewController {
                        if let presentedVC = controller.presentedViewController {
                            presentedVC.view.backgroundColor = .red
                            presentedVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                        }
                    }
                }
        })
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple finally added it to SwiftUI in iOS 16.4: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationcornerradius(_:)

Using the example that zouritre gave, it would look like this:

```swift
struct Example: View {
@State var showSheet = true
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("hello")
                .presentationCornerRadius(30)
        }
}
```